# From local time to international time?

Tags: r

I've a data frame of users that entered our site. The problem is the data is reported on Perú Time Zone (GMT-5) and I needed to be reported in the correct Time Zone for each country.

**Original DF:**

```
date        hour country      users
2019-12-01  00   Argentina     8
2019-12-01  00   Australia     1
2019-12-01  00   Bolivia       5
2019-12-01  00   Canada        10
```

**Expected DF:**

```
 date        hour  country      users
 2019-12-01  02    Argentina      8
 2019-12-01  10    Australia      1
 2019-12-01  01    Bolivia        5
 2019-12-01  00    Canada         10
```

Assuming: Time zone in Ottawa, ON, Canada (GMT-5), Time zone in Bolivia (GMT-4),  Time zone in Canberra ACT, Australia (GMT+11), Time zone in Buenos Aires, Argentina (GMT-3).

**data:**

```
dput(head(users_int, n=10))
structure(list(date = structure(c(18231, 18231, 18231, 18231, 
18231, 18231, 18231, 18231, 18231, 18231), class = "Date"), hour = c("00", 
"00", "00", "00", "00", "00", "00", "00", "00", "00"), country = c("Argentina", 
"Australia", "Bolivia", "Canada", "Central African Republic", 
"Chile", "Colombia", "Denmark", "Dominican Republic", "Ecuador"
), users = c(8, 1, 5, 10, 1, 12, 1, 1, 2, 2)), totals = list(
    list(users = "500823")), minimums = list(list(users = "1")), maximums = list(
    list(users = "1615")), isDataGolden = TRUE, rowCount = 20913L, nextPageToken = "10000", row.names = c(NA, 
10L), class = "data.frame")
```

**NOTE:** I'm just dputing some rows, please, lets consider all possbile countries may be included.

Comment: Your question is not clear. And you do know that many countries such as Austalia and USA have multiple time zones.

Comment: @Edward that is the complication, but a way to solve it would be to take the Capital State as reference.

Comment: You can get the time zones of the capitals from any website and convert based on that.

Comment: If you want "all possible countries" then you should be looking for a data resource and offering it as perhaps including the time zone of world capitals. Otherwise this is a "do all the work for me" request. Such requests are generally closed as "too broad".